# Django - how to get user logged in (get_queryset in ListView)

Tags: django

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Location(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

views.py

```
class UserLocationsListView(ListView):
    model = Location
    context_object_name = 'user_locations'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_locations = Location.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        paginator = Paginator(user_locations, 10)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            user_locations = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            user_locations = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            user_locations = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        return user_locations
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^member/user_locations/$', UserLocationsListView.as_view(), name='user_locations'),
```

I want the user to be able to see all of his locations at the page.

It seems I have problems with REQUEST (while filtering and in page definition)

How should I fix this?

Thanks!

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/member/user_locations/

Django Version: 1.8.6
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.instagram',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
 'crispy_forms',
 'findlocation_app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  164.                 response = response.render()
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  158.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  133.         template = self._resolve_template(self.template_name)
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in _resolve_template
  88.         new_template = self.resolve_template(template)
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in resolve_template
  78.             return loader.select_template(template, using=self.using)
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in select_template
  64.                     return engine.get_template(template_name, dirs)
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in get_template
  30.         return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name, dirs))
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in get_template
  167.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name, dirs)
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in find_template
  141.                 source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py" in __call__
  13.         return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py" in load_template
  17.             template_name, template_dirs)
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py" in load_template_source
  38.                     return fp.read(), filepath
File "C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\codecs.py" in decode
  314.         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /member/user_locations/
Exception Value: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 748: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to use the login required [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator or [mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) to prevent users who are not logged in from seeing the page. If location allowed the user field to be blank, you wouldn't want anonymous users to be able to see all locations without a user.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your question is completely unrelated to the traceback. The traceback shows that you have an invalid character (in position 748) in the template used by your view. Remove it.

The view itself looks ok. The correct way to get the user in the method is `self.request.user`, as you are already doing.

You could simplify the method slightly - you don't need to do the pagination in the method, the `ListView` will take care of that for you.

```
class UserLocationsListView(ListView):
    ...
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(UserLocationsListView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

Comment: I have done as you wrote above... I get the error - 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 748: invalid continuation byte

Comment: before I was getting the same error.. and only at this view

Comment: Please add the traceback to your question.

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError at /member/user_locations/
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcf in position 748: invalid continuation byte
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/member/user_locations/
Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError
Exception Location: C:\commercial_projects\fl\lib\codecs.py in decode, line 314
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

Comment: Add the full traceback to your question, not as a comment here. I don't think this has anything to do with your `get_queryset` method. My guess is that if you remove the method completely, you'll still get the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I've changed template and error has disappeared. But now :) the page is empty. I cheked 'queryset' through PRINT in the view and it showed me the empty list. In admin panel I've seen that locations created have not user (that created them) but admin name. Obviously, I am wrong in creating and connecting User to Location model. I renewed the models.py above, please look at that... thanks!

Comment: now when I am trying to add location I get error - IntegrityError at /add_location/
findlocation_app_location.user_id may not be NULL

Comment: These sound like new problems - please start a new question instead of asking in the comments.